# Workflows Firestore connector not supporting named databases

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-workflows

When i try to update a firestore database other then (default) i got this error:

```
"body": {
"error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Missing routing header. Please fill in the request header with format x-goog-request-params:project_id=xxxxxx&database_id=xxxx. Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases#access_a_named_database_with_a_client_library for more details.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
},
```

I think workflows firestore adapter don't support named databases, is this correct?

Comment: Based on the link on the error message, this feature is still in public preview and there might be issues with compatibility. One of its limitations as of the moment is if you're using Cloud Functions v1, it doesn't support Firestore Named databases. You need to use [Cloud Firestore Triggers (2nd Gen)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) to configure events for named databases.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment, yes I think the same, but the error is coming from gpc workflows not functions.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code? Can you also check if this [Github issue link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/15550) is similar with your issue?

Comment: Is the same issue in a other environment